# How to wait result of a function in React?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to fetch info from an endpoint and assign it to a local variable. The problem is that the info is fetched successfully and when I put console.log(resp.data) it is printed, so I assign it to the faculties, but in the following line faculties is an empty array. I tried async/await -> I defined showOptions function as async and awaited  facultiesService.getAllFaculties(), but the problem was not solved and some other errors occured. How can I solve this issue?

```
 const showOptions = () => {
            let faculties = [];
            facultiesService.getAllFaculties()
                .then(async (resp) => {
                    faculties = await resp.data;
                })
                .catch(e => console.log(e));
        console.log(faculties)
        return faculties.map(faculty => {
            return <option
                key={faculty.id}
                value={faculty.id}
            >{faculty.name}
            </option>
        });
    }

    const showFacultySelect = () => {

        return (
            <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example">
                {showOptions()}
            </Form.Select>
        )
    }
```

Comment: You are returning `faculties` immediately from your function, which is always empty because the data getting function you fired is asynchronous. Your console.log should be catching the fact it's empty. Read the answer below, or otherwise find a way to use state. Also, it appears you have this data-fetching code directly in the render cycle. This means you'll fetch data for _every_ render of that component. Put it in a useEffect() and useState to fetch once, and then store its results in state. This will also resolve your render timing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using async/await in wrong way. They are meant for sequential code rather than callbacks. You should be doing something like this:

```
const showOptions = async () => {
            let result = await facultiesService.getAllFaculties();
            let faculties = await resp.data;
           console.log(faculties)
        return faculties.map(faculty => {
            return <option
                key={faculty.id}
                value={faculty.id}
            >{faculty.name}
            </option>
        });
    }
```